# Serilize custom ArrayList to JSON

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I'm working on fixing an issue on an Android app using Java. I have a custom ArrayList which I want to pass to a server as JSON. I just want to know is this possible? When I pass in an ArrayList of type String it passes to the server perfectly fine. Any help or links to articles on this would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library from Google for converting ArrayList or even collection of custom complex type to JSON.

GSON provides you capability to register custom serializer/deserializers as well. See [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types).

To start with try following code snippet to serialize an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> arrayList = ...
Gson gson = new Gson();
String serializedJson = gson.toJson(arrayList);
```